# URL Unexpectedly found nil while Unwrapping

Tags: ios, swift, url

I have a Firebase Database where my image URL's are. I am trying to call the Profile Images based on the Profile User Name. I am getting the correct URL from profileImageURL, but whenever I am starting the URLSession it is always showing nil. Here is my code:

```
 if let profileImageURL = user.profileImageURL{

      let url = URL(string: profileImageURL)
      URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { ( data, response, error) in
           //Download Hit an Error
           if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
           }
           DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                     cell.profileNameImageView?.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                }
      })
 }
```

A sample url string:

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/instagram-caption-generator.appspot.com/o/FeaturedAccounts%2FProfileImage%2Ffeatured_2.jpg?alt=media&token=4a2774f5-f192-4f06-b7c1-a4044921c075

Comment: What's nil? `cell.profileNameImageView`? `url`? Is `profileImageURL` really a valid URL string? Does it have spaces? Unescaped characters?

Comment: The url is saying nil. profileImageURL is a valid string.

Comment: Can you copy/paste here?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a specific example of a `profileImageURL` value that is failing. Clearly it's not a valid URL string. Once you show it to us we can tell you why and how to fix it.

Comment: If it works on Safari, copy/paste it from Safari and compare, because Safari adds the percent escape for space for instance (%20)

Comment: Do not post an image of text, post text. Simply copy and paste the text of a single URL into your question.

Comment: @TDIFF Have you tried this link (url string) with web browser. Is it accessible (load any information or data) using browser in your system. I tried but it is not.

Comment: @Krunal I edited the link in the OP to show what the post is. This is the download link that I am testing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `if-let` block with URL initialiser. Reason for this error is optional instance of url - [init?(string: String)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/1779737-init). You `profileImageURL` may not be a valid url string and hence URL initialiser can't make an instance of class `URL` and returns nil, that you are trying to unwrap using `!`.

Try this and see.

```
if let profileImageURL = user.profileImageURL{

   // Use if-let block with URL initialiser.
  if let url = URL(string: profileImageURL) { // try this - if let url = URL(string: "gs://instagram-caption-generator.appspot.com/FeaturedAccoun‌​ts/ProfileImage/feat‌​ured_2.jpg") {

     // Remove unwrapper !, from url           
     URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { ( data, response, error) in
       //Download Hit an Error
         if error != nil {
             print(error!)
              return
         }

          if let imageData = data {
            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
              cell.profileNameImageView?.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            }
          } else {
            print("image data is nil")
          }
       }).resume()
  } else {
    print("url is nil")

  }
}
```

Comment: For each profileImageURL it prints nil still.

Comment: that's what I'm showing here - `profileImageURL` is not a valid string try this string see: `https://stackoverflow.com`

Comment: This doesn't actually fix the issue, it just avoids the crash.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. But OP had not provided url string that could be tested/validated. This answer is focusing on question statement `Unexpectedly found nil while Unwrapping`

Comment: The question was updated earlier with several example URLs. But this question has been closed as a duplicate.

Comment: This is now the correct answer. I added .resume() and everything now works as expected.

Comment: @TDIFF How is this now the correct answer? While this avoids the crash, it doesn't do anything to deal with the invalid URL string in `profileImageURL`.

Comment: The URL string is no longer nil. The sample link in the OP works in the application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `guard` or `if let` statement and unwrap `profileImageURL` *and* verify that it is actually a valid URL in one sweep like so:

```
guard let profileImageURL = user.profileImageURL,
      let url = URL(string: profileImageURL) else { return }

// now you know that url is definitely a valid URL
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { ( data, response, error) in
    //Download Hit an Error
     if error != nil {
         print(error!)
         return
     }

     DispatchQueue.main.async() {
         cell.profileNameImageView?.image = UIImage(data: data!)
     }
})
```

Saves you the force unwrapping `!` which cause you problems (as you just discovered).

Hope that helps.

Comment: This doesn't actually fix the issue, it just avoids the crash.

Comment: @rmaddy no you're right. It stops the crash but the imageView will remain empty.